# Cannot extend helper of third party module

Tags: module, helper, extend

My config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Company_Mailchimpextend>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Company_Mailchimpextend>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <helpers>
            <monkey><!-- tried MageMonkey, magemonkey etc. -->
                <rewrite>
                    <data>Company_Mailchimpextend_Helper_Data</data>
                </rewrite>
            </monkey>
        </helpers>
    </global>
</config>
```

etc/modules/Company_Mailchimpextend.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Company_Mailchimpextend>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
                <depends>
                <Ebizmarts_MageMonkey/>
            </depends>
        </Company_Mailchimpextend>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Helper/Data.php:

```
<?php
    class Company_Mailchimpextend_Helper_Data extends Ebizmarts_MageMonkey_Helper_Data {

        private function _setMaps($maps,$customer,$merge_vars, $websiteId)
        {
            Mage::log("test",null,"test.log");
```

Third party config.xml:

```
<helpers>
        <monkey>
            <class>Ebizmarts_MageMonkey_Helper</class>
        </monkey>
    </helpers>
```

It doesn't seem to be extended somewhere else. Cleared cache, the module is showing in config > advance. It still uses the method `_setMaps` from the third party module.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try overriding a not so private method?

Comment: @mam08ixo ok, thanks, beginners mistake. so it is essentially not possible to overwrite that private method in my module?  how should I deal with that because i cannot change the module file, on next update my change could be deleted.

Comment: Override the method that invokes the private part.

Comment: @mam08ixo thanks. if you have time please submit an answer so that I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overriding *private* methods has no effect, it does not even raise any PHP errors. In order to alter the behaviour of *private* parent methods you need to override the *public* or *protected* method that invokes the *private* one and change the behaviour there:

```
<?php
class Base
{
    private function _output()
    {
        return 'foo';
    }

    public function printOutput()
    {
        print $this->_output();
    }

    public function printMyOutput()
    {
        print $this->_output();
    }

    public function printMyOutput2()
    {
        print $this->_output();
    }
}

class Override extends Base
{
    private function _output()
    {
        return 'bar';
    }

    public function printMyOutput()
    {
        print $this->_output();
    }

    public function printMyOutput2()
    {
        print 'bar';
    }
}

$override = new Override();
$override->printOutput();    // prints 'foo'
$override->printMyOutput();  // prints 'bar'
$override->printMyOutput2(); // prints 'bar'
```

Personally, I would not even re-declare the private method but integrate its logic either directly into the overriden method or, if more complex, move it to a separate model.